# How to Detect vowels

Tags: .net, vb.net, string

I've created a program that bends Finnish grammar, and now I need some help. To make the program to work, I'll have to somehow make it capable of detecting vowels (a, e, i, o, u, y, ä, ö).

For example, if a word ends with two vowels it will bend the word on one way. If it ends with a vowel plus 'ta' or 'tä' it will bend it differently. If the word doesn't match any of these two, it will bend it on a third way.

I'm thankful for any help :)

EDIT:

```
' Handle singular
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If InStr(TextBox1.Text, "n") Then
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Remove(TextBox2.TextLength - 1, 1)
        TextBox3.Text = "älä " & TextBox2.Text
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "fel form"
    End If
End Sub
' Handle plural
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim str As String
    str = TextBox6.Text
    Dim vokal As String
    vokal = "a"
    If str.EndsWith(vokal + vokal) = True Then
        MsgBox("The string ends with a vokal!! ")
    Else
        MsgBox("Failure!")
    End If

    If InStr(TextBox6.Text, "n") Then
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Remove(TextBox2.TextLength - 1, 1)
        TextBox3.Text = "älä " & TextBox2.Text
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "fel form"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: 'bend' the word - what does that mean?

Comment: I think it's called like "change form" in English. I think it's unique for Finnish.

Comment: on client side (ex. jQuery) or on server side (VB)? Show your code would certainly help.

Comment: @Jamie The English term is "decline/conjugate" (depending on whether the base word is a noun, verb, or whatever). "Bend" is a literal translation from the Finnish. (And most languages do it, not just Finnish.)

Comment: Ok, you learn something new everyday :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could use a [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim input As String = ...
If Regex.IsMatch(input, "[aeiouyäö]{2}$") Then
    Console.WriteLine("This word ends with two vowels")
Else If Regex.IsMatch(input, "[aeiouyäö]{2}t[aä]$") Then
    Console.WriteLine("This word ends with two vowels and 'ta' or 'tä'")
Else
    Console.WriteLine("This word does not meet either of the other conditions")
End If
```

To explain some of the details about this code:

- `[aeiouyäö]` is a [character class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#character_classes) which matches a single character a, e, i, o, u, y, ä, ö.
- `{2}` is a [quatifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#quantifiers), which matches any two instances of the previous character, character class, or group.
- `$` is an [anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#atomic_zerowidth_assertions) which matches the end of the string (or line in multiline mode).

Comment: It's something like this I want, thanks, but I get build errors if I'm using this code: Expected beginning '<' for an XML tag. http://choo.ga/i/0I7b.png

Comment: @user3198523 well the `...` was just a placeholder to indicate that you would have to provide some code yourself (probably `TextBox6.Text`).